# Cloud Integration: An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I created a new GAE app, but the Cloud Integration section on the Settings page tells me that "An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry."

I have pressed the Retry button multiple times over a period of many hours, but it's just not working.  I found [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=9602), which repeatedly says that the issue is solved, but it's not resolved for me.

Is anyone from Google monitoring this forum? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution seems to be to create a new app, and hope for the best (it worked for me). Sadly, if you delete the problem app, the app-id is lost forever.

Comment: i am having same issue, is there any other solution other than creating a new app?

Comment: I never found a way to rescue the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but in case someone else stumbles on this question.

In the google cloud console, activate billing from the Storage>Cloud Storage > Browser tab, then activate / retry under Cloud Integration from appengine.google.com.

I didn't need to create a new app id, when I went that route.