# How do I get a Google Admin to Fix my Project Console?

Tags: google-app-engine

Short of [paying $150/month](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3420040#silver_details) so I can actually submit a ticket, what can I do to get Google's attention?  I've seen other people get help for what appears to be the exact same issue.

I uploaded a new (small) app to Google App Engine (GAE), and the Applications Settings page shows an error under Cloud Integration ("An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry").

I've retried over a period of days, but it tries for a while, then reports another failure.  I've asked questions of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315758/cloud-integration-an-error-occurred-when-creating-the-project-please-retry), and in the [GAE issues forum](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), to no response.

Comment: I finally gave up on trying to attract Google's attention.  Fortunately, I was able to create a different app ID and have it work, but I'm sad that my original, carefully picked-out ID is forever lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get hold of the people from Google Developer relations here, in the relevant Google+ communities or on Google groups.

If it can bring you any comfort: paying the $150 does not help you much - we have the subscription.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do :-/  Thanks for the advice about the support, although I'd have to believe it would at least work for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a second Google Apps domain, replicate the issue by switching domains and recreating the project from scratch. Then if the error occurs again, post that it occurs in 2 or more cloud.google.com accounts with separate domains.  This should help show this is not a one off error and requires investigation.

If it does not occur in the second domain, save your data, delete your project and recreate with a different project name and number.

-ExGenius